# Transfer Kindle books to Toshiba Thrive

Tags: kindle

I have the basic model Kindle and I have many books on it that I would like to transfer to my Toshiba Thrive.  The catch is that I do not have WIFI or internet access where I am located.  Is there a way to just transfer the files.

Comment: Do you have any way to connect the two devices?

Comment: I cannot find a "kindle" folder on my Thrive where the kindle app stores books so I would not know where to copy them.

Comment: I do not think that kindles or Thrives are computer in the context for a SU question. If this was to transfer files from one of the tables to a computer or visa versa it would be an acceptable question here. VTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The books will be available as .mobi files in your Kindle internal memory, in a folder called `documents` or similar. You can use the Kindle as a normal USB drive, but you need a PC to transfer the files, or it may be possible to use the tablet as host (I'm not sure about that).

If you bought them, there is a high chance that they will be DRM protected, so you couldn't be able to transfer them.

Comment: The books are actually from the public library system via Overdrive.

Comment: @BoundforPNG: I don't know what Overdrive is; can't you use a laptop for the transfer?

Comment: Overdrive is a system that many public libraries use to manage and loan eBooks.